# Fastest way to chown a whole device (xfs)

Tags: linux, xfs, chown

I need to chown 1.5 million files on a drive. I'm currently doing:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /root-of-device
```

but it takes an awfully long time to run. I was wondering if there was some sort of superfast low-level way to chown every file on the drive.

Comment: How about using a umask on the folder  (in some situation) ? 

  chown www-data:www-data /var/www  &&   chmod -R ug+rwxs /var/www

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `xargs -p` or GNU `parallel` to speed things up considerably.

Comment: On a single filesystem, the speedup will be less than you think; potentially it could be *slower* because of contention between the multiple threads of execution accessing the same filesystem.

Comment: That should not be the case in XFS, as it supports parallel meta data operation according to the number of allocation groups created at formatting time. A parallel chmod will be faster than the sequential version.

Comment: I tried xargs -P4 (number of allocation groups on my xfs) and it ran slightly faster than the regular chown. I ran it a few times though and I think the difference in timings was just AWS EBS i/o fluctuations.

Comment: So what's the complete pipe using `chown ...` and `xargs -p` ?

Comment: @pfo an explanation and example adds that nice luster of completeness.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I do not think there is such a thing, but I would be pleasantly surprised if there was. You could write your own implementation in C and optimise it heavily. However the success of that depends on how well optimized **chown** is to begin with. And considering it's one of the core utilities I would say it's rather optimized. In addition you are bound most likely by i/o speed.

I have had some success avoiding limitations of **ls** and **rm** by piping the results of **find** to **xargs**, in the case a directory has a lot of files, i.e.:

```
find /path/* | xargs rm
```

So, a wild guess, maybe this can speed up **chown**, in case it is slower at recursively scanning a filesystem than **find**:

```
sudo find /path/* | xargs chown www-data:www-data
```

Comment: Ha! Don't fancy my chances of coming up with a better implementation to be honest. It's an Amazon EBS device which means that i/o performance is a bit unstable.

Comment: I updated my answer with a few suggestions that may help.

Comment: In theory you could abuse `xfs_metadump` and `xfs_db` to get something slightly faster; in practice it's not worth the effort or the potential failure modes.

Comment: Yeah I think whichever way you look at it it will take a long time...

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Playing around with various things it really looks like I'm not going to do much better than regular chown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Amazon EC2 as well and had this issue. 2 things:

**Fixing Current situation:** You will have to deal with the slowness. Perhaps you can use "screen" or something similar so that the process can continue in the background.

**Fixing Future situation:** You could look upstream and see how the files are being generated in the first place. Since you mentioned www-data, I'm assuming that the consumer of the files is Apache. If files are being dropped from another program (NFS, Samba, SSH etc) make sure that those programs are setting the user:group as www-data:www-data.

Comment: `screen(1)` is a solution, but perhaps better is to use `nohup(1)`.